# How to find the paragraph node is within the table node in OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I have tried in the following code sample the Ancestor property to find the paragraph node within the table node but it's not working for all cases.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument Docx = WordprocessingDocument.Open(DocxStream, true))
{
    Body DocxBody = Docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    List<OpenXmlElement> EachPara = new List<OpenXmlElement>();//Paragraph element
    foreach (OpenXmlElement bodyChild in DocxBody.ChildElements)
    {
        if (bodyChild is Paragraph)
        {
            if (bodyChild.Ancestors<Table>().ToList().Count > 0)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    //  List<OpenXmlElement> EachPara = DocxBody.ChildElements.ToList().Where(eachChild => eachChild is Paragraph).ToList();
    foreach (OpenXmlElement lstPara in EachPara)
    {
        if (lstPara.ChildElements.Any(ch => ch.LocalName.ToLower().Equals("run")))
        {

        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

}
```